# Pandas - Taking max of one column for multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'location':['LA','LA','SF','LA','SF','LA','SF'], 'col2': [1, 3, 5, 2, 8, 5, 7], 'col3': [11, 14, 54, 67, 2, 9, 45]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['location', 'col2', 'col3'])
print df

 location  col2  col3
0       LA     1    11
1       LA     3    14
2       SF     5    54
3       LA     2    67
4       SF     8     2
5       LA     5     9
6       SF     7    45
```

I want to groupby "location" and then take the max of "col2" of all the rows that I grouped by, but I do not want the max of "col3". I want "col3"'s value to be the same value as the row of "col3", which has the max "col2" for that location.  How I want the dataframe to look when done is:

```
  location  col2  col3
0       LA     5     9
1       SF     8     2
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if anything is unclear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `groupby('location').col2` as expected
- however, grab `idxmax()` and use this in `loc` on full `df`

---

```
df.loc[df.groupby('location').col2.idxmax()]

  location  col2  col3
5       LA     5     9
4       SF     8     2
```